# Using Laravel to Add Dynamic Attributes to Form Fields

Tags: forms, laravel, dynamic, attributes

I am trying to create a dynamic value for a form attribute that is auto-populated based on a previous setting stored in the database.  It works fine in HTML with a little Laravel and looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="class" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="{{ $user->firstName }}">
```

But I want to fully generate the entire form in Laravel.  I'm unsure how to pass the value into the array.  I can't seem to get the form to pull the information.  Here is how it is currently looking:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name', '', [
'class'       => 'class',
'id'          => 'firstName',
'placeholder' => 'First Name',
'value'       => $user->firstName
])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name', $user->firstName, [
'class'       => 'class',
'id'          => 'firstName',
'placeholder' => 'First Name'
])}}
```

For more information regarding this topic, visit [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#text)

See, if that works.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a default value in laravel's form generator, the second value you pass in is made for you:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name', $user->firstName, 
    [
     'class'       => 'class',
     'id'          => 'firstName',
     'placeholder' => 'First Name',
    ]
  ) }}
```

Please note that from laravel 5, being published next week, the form helpers are removed (and for the actual state the installable replacement packages don't work very well/without bugs). So if you are planning on upgrading to laravel 5 better don't use this, instead go with html form elements.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example.  That works for value, but how would you do it for a dynamic class or dynamic id?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  Thanks!  You would just assign it like.

{{ Form::text('first_name', $user->firstName, 
    [
     'class'       => 'class',
     'id'          => '$user->firstName',
     'placeholder' => 'First Name',
    ]
  ) }}